# How to run Brushless Motor with raspberry pi 4

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

I'm using raspberry pi 4 with the pigpio library. I can get the motor to turn on by entering the following commands into the terminal but how do I run the motor with python in visual studio code lets say.

Commands:

```
sudo pigpiod
pigs s 13 2000 #used to arm the esc
pigs s 13 1000 #used to arm the esc
pigs s 13 1100
```

As I said this works fine. The motor is connected to GPIO pin 13. I've had a look at the documentation but I didn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get stuck you can look through the examples.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html

To replicate that pigs in Python try something like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import pigpio

SERVO=13

pi = pigpio.pi()

if not pi.connected:
   exit()

# step 1 to arm the esc
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(SERVO, 2000)
time.sleep(1)

# step 2 to arm the esc
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(SERVO, 1000)
time.sleep(1)

# set motor speed
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(SERVO, 1100)
time.sleep(10)

pi.stop()
```

Save the Python code to, say, example.py then run as follows.

```
sudo pigpiod # only needed once per session

python example.py
```

Comment: thanks that worked, my ESC automatically arms when I plug in the battery (external power) so I'm assuming the code for the arming process is redundant in this case?

Comment: I suppose so.  You will have to try it and see.  I normally just use servos directly (which do not need arming).

Comment: Is there a way I can reverse the direction of the motor through software?